# Equivalent of .NET's WebClient and HttpWebRequest in Java?

Tags: java, .net, language-comparisons

.NET has the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) classes for simulating a browser's requests.

I'd google it, but I'm not sure what keyword to use.

I want to write code that does does HTTP GETs and POSTs, along with cookies, in an applet or local `.jar` and gives me back the response in a text string or some other parseable structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`HttpURLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) is Java's equivalent of `HttpWebRequest`.

```
URL iurl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)iurl.openConnection();
uc.connect();
if (uc.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg"))
{
  result = true;
}
```

Comment: Do You know  the java Equivallent of HttpWebResponse

Answer (score 7):

[Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/features.html) has equivalent functionality, though the APIs are not exactly the same. Oakland Software has a [table](http://www.oaklandsoftware.com/product_http/compare.html) comparing their commercial product with various alternatives, including the Apache product. Apache's own opinion of the built-in HttpUrlConnection (quoted from the above linked-to page) is:

> The jdk has the HttpUrlConnection
>   which is limited and in many ways
>   flawed.

Here's a link to the HTTPClient [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

html unit for me.
i can simulate javascript (to a certain extent)

Comment: I think he's actually referring to httpunit: http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/WebClient.html

Answer (score 1):

Verify Webclient in Apache Cx JaxRs Library.

Checkout this:
https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html

Sample code looks below:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(url);
client.path(ADD_PATH).path("/books/2").accept("text/plain");
s = client.get(String.class);
System.out.println(s);
```