# Android - write Website HTML to text file

Tags: android, html, web

It is my beginning with Android and I would like to write an app to connect with certain website, then save whole html of this website to some text file. I need this to later purposes such as extracting some info from html and so on. Do I need to do it using WebView?

Details: The website contains job offers. I need to make a connection with fields responsible for description and location of a job, so my application can fill those fields. Next step would be listing all the results.

Please lend me some advice :)

Comment: Look at the accepted answer at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137812/equivallent-of-nets-webclient-and-httpwebrequest-in-java. That should do it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the html-source of a page from a html link in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423498/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-page-from-a-html-link-in-android)